# Having issues with "Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'"

Tags: reactjs, flask

I am trying to connect my React code with the flask one. The problem is I constantly get issues with "Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'" and I don't know what to try else:
What I've tried till now:

- removed headers part completely
- tried to change somehow the method
- tried to add conditions in the flask app function
  Result: nothing
  Here is the snippet from flask app:

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import html
from flask import Flask
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS 

import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/api/predict',methods=['POST','GET'])
def home():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        input_data = request.json.get('input')
        output = f'f_{input_data}'
        response = jsonify({'output': output})
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        return response
    else:
        return "f*ing error b*"



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=3000, debug=True)
```

And the code from React:

```
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
    const [responseText, setResponseText] = useState('');

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        setInputText(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
    };
    const response = await fetch('/api/predict', requestOptions);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setResponseText(data.output);

  }
```

I expect some proposals at least. IDK, some solutions (i am desperate). I am sorry, I am a novice in flask so don't judge me please.